# How to pick a max number of items in a sequence that needs to have k items between them?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I'm studying Algorithms and I usually stumble upon this kind of question. Ok, I have an list of numbers and I have to find the max sub-list of this list in which the distance between each number is equals to or greater than the size of the list. For instance:

`[1, 3, 5, 10]`

The distance in this case is 4. Then, `[1, 5, 10]` would be the correct answer. Just to have in mind that when I remove the number `3`, the distance is now 3.

Any intuitions would be welcomed, I don't even know how to approach this problem. I tried generating possible paths for each number, like, `[1,5,9,13]`, but I could not come up with a way to pick the number to remove. This kind of problem is claimed to be solvable in O(N).

Comment: is the list sort ... initally ?

Comment: in the case [1, 3, 7, 11] .... which is the solution [1, 7, 11] or [3, 7, 11] or both or any?

Comment: Do you want to find any such list (in this case, the trivial answer is to take the empty list) or an optimal list? In the latter case, what thing do you want to have optimized?

Comment: @FUZxxl I'm sorry. I edit it. It has to be the max sub-list, i.e. in the case `[3,10]` could not be the answer.

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. both would be ok.

Comment: @JuGonçalves Maximum as in “of greatest sum” or as in “of greatest length?”

Comment: @FUZxxl greatest length.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy.

1. First compute all distances between the successive numbers in initial list `[1, 3, 5, 10]` -> `[2, ,2 , 5]` and remember the length. It's O(n) operation.
2. Notice that then you remove the number from the initial list you just sum 2 values in the distances list and decrease the length of the list by one. s This observation leads to the second greedy O(n) procedure. You just pass through the list of distances and compare them with the current length of the list. If distance >= length, go to the next element. If distance is lower then the length, remove this element (merge two distances) and reduce the length by one and check again...

After each step all your previous distances > length > new reduced length. And in the end of the procedure you get what you wanted.

Comment: What happens if you remove a number towards the end of the list. The list length now decreases creating new candidate numbers for removal. Will you iterate over the differences once again then? If yes then your algorithm runs in O(N^2) time and not linearly.

Comment: @NikunjBanka If i remove numbers in the end of the list i finish algorithm because even if the current distance < length it's no longer required.

Answer (score 0):

the following algorithm is O (N) and I think solves the problem, I'm trying different test cases

```
read(a)
N <- len(a)
solution <- []
if a[N-1]-a[0] < N then
  return solution
else
  last = a[0]
  solution.push(a[0])
  for i = 1 to N-1
    if a[i]-last >= N then
      solution.push(a[i])
      last = a[i]
    end if
  end for
  return solution
end if
```